# Pass get_option value to an array

Tags: php

I want to pass get_option value to an array value. This the value that I want to pass to the array.

```
<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('a')); ?>
```

and this is what I am trying to do.

```
<?php $var = array( 'foo' =>'echo stripslashes(get_option('a'));');
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: This is about PHP syntax, not about something specific to WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple variable to store the value.

```
 $a_val = stripslashes(get_option('a')); 
 $var = array( 'foo' => $a_val);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian Fegter and deepa for you kind support. I'll really appreciate and will be thankful to you people if you please get some time and have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751766/how-can-i-dynamically-edit-jw-player-javascript and if you can answer, please do.